# Creating a Scraping function in R, using a variable dependent on a Weblink

Tags: r, function, web-scraping, rvest, paste

I am trying to create a function that would automatically scrape the table for moves learned by level up of any given pokemon based on the pokemon name from the pokemondb website, the issue comes in my usage of paste0 in relation to the pokemon database link.

```
move_list <- function(pokemon){
  url <- paste0("https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/", pokemon)
  list_table <- 
    read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//table[@class = "data-table"]') %>% 
    html_table()
  level_up <- list_table[[1]]
  return(print(level_up))
}


move_list(donphan)
```

Error in paste0("https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/", pokemon) :
object 'donphan' not found

With the goal to vary the pokemon the table is scraped from based on their name, I used paste0 to put together the input of the function with the link to generate the proper website to scrape, but for some reason this does not work. I wondered if it had to do with the name of the input being "pokemon" so I tried different things like "string" "x" etc. I also tried putting "pokemon" in place of pokemon, but then the link would go to "https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/pokemon" every time which of course does not exist. How can I make the input correspond to the respective link of pokemon within this function?

Comment: It looks like you are passing a string and not a variable.  Strings need to be enclosed with quotes.  Try 
move_list(“donphan”)

Comment: This was my issue! Thank you so much it now functions as expected.